# How to display multiple JSON Object simultaneously in postman?

Tags: java, postman, rest

```
public String doStock(JsonObject SymbolName) throws Exception {
        JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject(SymbolName);
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj2.get("SymbolName");
        
        JSONObject obj3 = new JSONObject();
        Object obj = null;
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Symbol Name: ");
        //Iterating the contents of the array
        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
            obj = jsonArray.get(i);  
            System.out.println(obj);
            obj3=checkStock(obj.toString());
          
        }
    
        return obj3.toString();
     
    }
```

my post request : {"SymbolName":["ODP","ACC"]} in this only the details regarding ACC is returning to postman but in console both are showing, I want to display the json object regarding both ODP ans ACC. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with PostMan, but with your response object.

You will need to create a wrapper method which will compose the different "SymbolName" return objects into a new object.

Based on the code you have shown, I understand that you need to iterate through each of your symbolname using a method named doStock(), inside which you run the checkStock(symbolname) method for each symbolname, append the return object of the checkStock method into an array/List and finally when all the symbolnames are processed, return the array/List.

This array will have all your json objects.

In your code obj3 is getting over written in the loop and that is why you only get to see one object in postman, which will be the last obj3 you return.

Please see the modified code below:

```
public List doStock(JsonObject SymbolName) throws Exception {
        JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject(SymbolName);
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj2.get("SymbolName");
        
        JSONObject obj3 = new JSONObject();
        List returnList = new ArrayList()
        Object obj = null;
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Symbol Name: ");
        //Iterating the contents of the array
        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
            obj = jsonArray.get(i);  
            System.out.println(obj);
            obj3=checkStock(obj);
            returnList.add(obj3)
        }
    
        return returnList;
     
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, Actually I am learning these concepts now. Can you please explain in detail, how to create this wrapper method? @ Navaneeth Sen

Comment: Actually this wrapper method was a generic way of saying it, but in fact your doStock method is the wrapper code that compose this new return object for you.

Comment: I edited my code, but I got, [
    {
        "escapeForwardSlashAlways": true
    },
    {
        "escapeForwardSlashAlways": true
    }
]   @Navaneeth Sen

Comment: could you please print your obj3?

Comment: Actually it is solved today, I just added returnlist.tostring() , Thank you so much for your help. @Navaneeth Sen

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue this morning. the reason was inconsistent type of JSON classes we've used throughout our app.